# How can I delete a website login in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-management, auto-form-fill

I believe this is an autofill issue rather than a stored password facilities issue, although I am not sure that it's either.

Sometime ago, I set up an account on one particular website with a username of `abc` and a password of `XYZ`. One time, I accidentally typed much of the password in the username, and now Chrome remembers both a username of `abc` and `aXYbc`.

What can I do to delete the "most or all of username interrupted by most of the password" from Chrome's records.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when the auto-fill appears, you can hit the down arrow on your keyboard to highlight the choices in the list (abc, aXYbc, etc.).

You can use the up and down arrows to move up and down the list.

When aXYbc is highlighted, press the `Delete` key on your keyboard and that choice will disappear and not be offered again.

Comment: Thank you; I've tried both "Del" and "Backspace" and neither seems to delete the option.